# Add 2 buttons in Wordpress Hirebee theme from Appthemes

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the Wordpress Hirebee theme from Appthemes.

Link to theme features: https://www.appthemes.com/themes/hirebee/

Link to theme demo: http://demos.appthemes.com/?theme=hirebee

The theme already has a messaging and notification system for freelancers and employers to communicate with each other. So I want to:

- Make two buttons on profile. One button will be "Contact Me". It will send a normal message to the Freelancer.
- Second button will be "Hire me" button. It will invite the freelancer to an open project already created by the employer/user. To use the Hire me button, employer/user have to create a project first, then look for freelancers and invite anyone they like from the profile. If no project is created when the the hire me button is clicked, it should show a popup message saying to create a project first with a link to Create a project page.
- Both the above buttons should work along with the theme's existing notification system so users will get notifications for any messages or replies.

If someone used Hirebee theme please let me know how to do that.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

We are currently trying to set up this same theme and that is a good question. I been waiting to see if anyone answers you.

Michelle

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In the future, please only respond to the question if you have an answer - This would be more suited as a comment.